# why ".user.ini" can be placed outside of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?

Tags: php, shared-hosting, php-ini

My server is hosting some sites and I have some site specific settings for each site, so I put a .user.ini file under each site's document root directory.

According to PHP documentation:

> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).

However, to my surprise, even if I placed the .user.ini file outside of a site's document_root, it's still working, as long as it's within the path of the script. For example, if I'm running a script `https://A_DOMAIN_com/foo/bar/abc.php`, and in the server its real path is `/www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/foo/bar/abc.php`, where the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] has been set to `/www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/`.

Then even if I place the `.user.ini` file inside any of its path, e.g. `/www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/`, or `/www/public_html/`, or even `/www/`, the `.user.ini` file is still effective.

Is this a bug or expected behaivor?

I'm running PHP 7.0.15, the script is triggered by php-cgi7, the os is alpine.

Refs: [.user.ini files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

Comment: It will check the whole document tree branch on that account, it does exactly as it says in the quote you quoted.

Comment: the `user.ini` is *NOT* in your apparent case being placed "outside" of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: @Martin the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is set to /www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/, but the setting defined in .user.ini is still effective even if I place the .user.ini file under `/www/`. Is this still normal?

Comment: Yes, this is normal, because `/www/` is ***within*** `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: According to the documentation, isn't php-cgi supposed to start searching for ini files from `/www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/foo/bar/`, and end at `/www/public_html/A_DOMAIN_com/` ?

Comment: I thought I knew the answer, but I must admit the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) seems to contradict what I thought I knew.....

Comment: I believe `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is the *web* root of the account *not* the actual account filepath root